# Exporting to gLTF gives me a wrong orientation in Three.js

Tags: gltf, three.js

I have an animation in FBX format that I want to export with Blender to gLTF to be used on a model in Three.js (FBX format, which is the original, gives me other problems...). But, when I do it, the animation is played in the wrong orientation, no matter if I rotate it, it's always oriented to the top:
[image: Wrong orientation]
https://vimeo.com/691002320

It probably is because the option "Transform: +Y Up" is marked in Blender export because, when I unmark it, the orientation is fixed, but the model gets deformed. It seems that the animation is no longer synchronized with the model skeleton:
[image: Deformed model]
https://vimeo.com/691002279

What's the problem?

This is the animation file: http://formulamanager.com/tennis/modelos/John/J_Forced_Backhand.glb

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Also consider reporting a bug to the [glTF exporter issue tracker](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO) or Blender itself. In either case I think you'll need to share a `.blend` for others to reproduce and fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I'm very new to Blender and the 3D world in general, I have serious doubts about it being a bug haha. I'd like to read the opinion of some experienced users because I have no idea on what to search to find the solution